# d3js append circle shape on line element in Force directed graph?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, force-layout

I'm trying to add red circle which would appear on the line between nodes (possible centered) in my force directed graph.

I tried to solve it with adding it to `line.link` similar to like I'm adding lines, with new variable:

```
var linkcirc = vis.selectAll("line.link")
            .data(data.links)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("r",5)
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.target.y; })
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.source.x+60; })
            .attr("class", "linecircle")
            .attr("fill","red");
```

and on force tick I added:

```
linkcirc.attr("cy", function(d) { return d.target.y; })
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.source.x+60; })
```

They do show up but I don't know how to position them in the right place, At the middle of the nodes... How to use source, target position or something else so red circles show up in the center of links?...

you can see my situation for now here: http://jsfiddle.net/nAAbn/

and the script looks like this:

```
var data = {"nodes":[
                        {"name":"YHO", "full_name":"Yahoo", "type":1, "slug": "www.yahoo.com", "entity":"company", "img_hrefD":"", "img_hrefL":""},
                        {"name":"GGL", "full_name":"Google", "type":2, "slug": "www.google.com", "entity":"company", "img_hrefD":"", "img_hrefL":""},
                        {"name":"BNG", "full_name":"Bing", "type":2, "slug": "www.bing.com", "entity":"company", "img_hrefD":"", "img_hrefL":""},
                        {"name":"YDX", "full_name":"Yandex", "type":2, "slug": "www.yandex.com", "entity":"company", "img_hrefD":"", "img_hrefL":""},

                        {"name":"Desc1", "type":4, "slug": "", "entity":"description"},
                        {"name":"Desc2", "type":4, "slug": "", "entity":"description"},
                        {"name":"Desc4", "type":4, "slug": "", "entity":"description"},

                        {"name":"CEO", "prefix":"Mr.", "fst_name":"Jim", "snd_name":"Bean", "type":3, "slug": "", "entity":"employee"},
                        {"name":"ATT", "prefix":"Ms.", "fst_name":"Jenna", "snd_name":"Jameson", "type":3, "slug": "", "entity":"employee"},
                        {"name":"CTO", "prefix":"Mr.", "fst_name":"Lucky", "snd_name":"Luke", "type":3, "slug": "", "entity":"employee"},
                        {"name":"CDO", "prefix":"Ms.", "fst_name":"Pamela", "snd_name":"Anderson", "type":3, "slug": "", "entity":"employee"},
                        {"name":"CEO", "prefix":"Mr.", "fst_name":"Nacho", "snd_name":"Vidal", "type":3, "slug": "", "entity":"employee"},
                    ], 
            "links":[
                        {"source":0,"target":4,"value":1,"distance":5},
                        {"source":0,"target":5,"value":1,"distance":5},
                        {"source":0,"target":6,"value":1,"distance":5},

                        {"source":1,"target":4,"value":1,"distance":5},
                        {"source":2,"target":5,"value":1,"distance":5},
                        {"source":3,"target":6,"value":1,"distance":5},

                        {"source":7,"target":3,"value":10,"distance":6},
                        {"source":8,"target":3,"value":10,"distance":6},
                        {"source":9,"target":1,"value":10,"distance":6},
                        {"source":10,"target":1,"value":10,"distance":6},
                        {"source":11,"target":2,"value":10,"distance":6},
                        ]
               }    



    var w = 560,
        h = 500,
        radius = d3.scale.log().domain([0, 312000]).range(["10", "50"]);

    var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);


    //d3.json(data, function(json) {
        var force = self.force = d3.layout.force()
            .nodes(data.nodes)
            .links(data.links)
            .linkDistance(function(d) { return (d.distance*20); })
            //.friction(0.5)
            .charge(-250)
            .size([w, h])
            .start();



        var link = vis.selectAll("line.link")
            .data(data.links)
            .enter().append("svg:line")
            .style("stroke","blue")
            .attr("class", function (d) { return "link" + d.value +""; })
            .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; })


        var linkcirc = vis.selectAll("line.link")
            .data(data.links)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("r",5)
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.target.y; })
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.source.x+60; })
            .attr("class", "linecircle")
            .attr("fill","red");




        function openLink() {
            return function(d) {
                var url = "";
                if(d.slug != "") {
                    url = d.slug
                } //else if(d.type == 2) {
                    //url = "clients/" + d.slug
                //} else if(d.type == 3) {
                    //url = "agencies/" + d.slug
                //}
                window.open("//"+url)
            }
        }




        var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
            .data(data.nodes)
          .enter().append("svg:g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .call(force.drag);


        node.append("circle")
            .attr("class", function(d){ return "node type"+d.type})
            .attr("r",function(d){if(d.entity == "description"){ return 6 } else { return 18 }})
            //.on("mouseover", expandNode);
            //.style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.type); })



        node.append("svg:image")
            .attr("class", function(d){ return "circle img_"+d.name })
            .attr("xlink:href", function(d){ return d.img_hrefD})
            .attr("x", "-36px")
            .attr("y", "-36px")
            .attr("width", "70px")
            .attr("height", "70px")
            .on("click", openLink())
            .on("mouseover", function (d) { if(d.entity == "company")
                                                {
                    d3.select(this).attr("width", "90px")
                                    .attr("x", "-46px")
                                    .attr("y", "-36.5px")
                                   .attr("xlink:href", function(d){ return d.img_hrefL});                           
                                                }
                })
            .on("mouseout", function (d) { if(d.entity == "company")
                                            {
                    d3.select(this).attr("width", "70px")
                                    .attr("x", "-36px")
                                    .attr("y", "-36px")
                                   .attr("xlink:href", function(d){ return d.img_hrefD});
                                            }
                });    


        node.append("text")
            .attr("class", function(d){ return "nodetext title_"+d.name })
            .attr("dx", 0)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .style("font-size","10px")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("fill", "white")
            .text(function(d) { if (d.entity != "description"){return d.name} });



        node.on("mouseover", function (d) {
            if (d.entity == "company"){   
                d3.select(this).select('text')
                    .transition()
                    .duration(300)
                    .text(function(d){
                            return d.full_name;
                        })
                    .style("font-size","15px")

            }
            else if(d.entity == "employee"){
                var asdf = d3.select(this);
                asdf.select('text').remove();

                asdf.append("text")
                            .text(function(d){return d.prefix + ' ' + d.fst_name })
                            .attr("class","nodetext")
                            .attr("dx", 0)
                            .attr("dy", ".35em")
                            .style("font-size","5px")
                            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                            .style("fill", "white")
                            .transition()
                            .duration(300)
                            .style("font-size","12px");

                asdf.append("text").text(function(d){return d.snd_name })
                            .attr("class","nodetext")
                            .attr("transform","translate(0, 12)")
                            .attr("dx", 0)
                            .attr("dy", ".35em")
                            .style("font-size","5px")
                            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                            .style("fill", "white")
                            .transition()
                            .duration(300)
                            .style("font-size","12px");                                         
            }
            else {
                d3.select(this).select('text')
                    .transition()
                    .duration(300)
                    .style("font-size","15px")
            }

            if (d.entity == "company") {
                d3.select(this).select('image')
                    .attr("width", "90px")
                    .attr("x", "-46px")
                    .attr("y", "-36.5px")
                    .attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
                        return d.img_hrefL
                        });               
            }

            if (d.entity == "company") {

                d3.select(this).select('circle')
                                .transition()
                                .duration(300)
                                .attr("r",28)

            }
            else if (d.entity == "employee"){
                d3.select(this).select('circle')
                                .transition()
                                .duration(300)
                                .attr("r",32)
            }
        })


         node.on("mouseout", function (d) {
            if (d.entity == "company") {
                d3.select(this).select('text')
                    .transition()
                    .duration(300)
                    .text(function(d){return d.name;})
                    .style("font-size","10px")
                }
            else if(d.entity == "employee"){
                ///////////////////////////
                // CHANGE
                ///////////////////////////

                d3.select(this).selectAll('text').remove();

                //d3.select(this).select('text')
                d3.select(this).append('text')
                    .text(function(d){return d.name;})
                    .style("font-size","14px")  
                    .attr("dx", 0)
                    .attr("dy", ".35em")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .style("fill", "white")
                    .attr("class","nodetext")
                    .transition()
                    .duration(300)
                    .style("font-size","10px")

            }
            else {
                d3.select(this).select('text')
                    .transition()
                    .duration(300)
                    .style("font-size","10px")
            }


             if (d.entity == "company") {
                d3.select(this).select('image')
                    .attr("width", "70px")
                    .attr("x", "-36px")
                    .attr("y", "-36px")
                    .attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
                    return d.img_hrefD
                });
            }

            if (d.entity == "company" || d.entity == "employee") {

                d3.select(this).select('circle')
                                .transition()
                                .duration(300)
                                .attr("r",18)
            }

        });

        force.on("tick", function() {
          link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
              .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
              .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
              .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

          node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

           linkcirc.attr("cy", function(d) { return d.target.y; })
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.source.x+60; })
        });
    //});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply add the coordinates and divide them by 2 to get the center position:

```
linkcirc
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return (d.source.y + d.target.y)/2; })
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return (d.source.x + d.target.x)/2; });
```

Updated jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nAAbn/1/).